# Bug: 100% brightness on resume?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, xfce, ubuntu-mate

When I wake my system from resume, its brightness is 100%, each time.  I have xfce, but it did not work.  xfce also is not sending me critically low battery notifications.  Any advice?

Comment: There are "dim display" options in the MATE and xfce power tools, but there is no brightness control.  I'm not sure why the brightness is re-adjusting itself on resume from suspend.